# Same Origin Policy seemingly inconsistent using jQuery AJAX API

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, same-origin-policy

I'm trying to understand how the Same Origin Policy (SOP) applies in different situations.

I have the following JavaScript code written in a local HTML file and run with Chrome on Windows:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.get("http://www.quandl.com/api/v1/datasets/FRED/GDP.json", function (r) {
        window.alert(r.source_name);
    });
});
```

It works by giving me data retrieved from another domain (`www.quandl.com`). However, if I swap that with `google.com`, the callback won't be invoked:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.get("http://www.google.com", function (r) {
        window.alert(r);
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure why the first one works, but I believe the problem with the second is that Google defaults to HTTPS.  Try cnn.com or something.

Comment: because the first resource supports CORS and the second one doesn't

Comment: looks at the response header for the first request you can find some headers like `Access-Control-Allow-*`

Comment: There is a good summary in Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the inconsistency here is due to the fact that the first resource has an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header, so it supports [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) and allows scripts from all domains to access the data with AJAX and [XMLHttpRequests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).

By contrast, `google.com` does not, so trying to access it from another domain will give you the usual errors.

Adding that header to any page will circumvent the Same Origin Policy. You could also do `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: domain` to only allow requests from the domain `domain`.

Take a look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing#Simplified_example) for more information on CORS support.